# Close Intermediate Files After Loop Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I wrote a pyspark script to loop through tables in a hive database and do something with them (can't say exactly what per company policy), for example:

```
hc = HiveContext(sc)
for table in tables:
    df = hc.sql("select * from {}".format(table))
    df.do_something()
    df.unpersist()
```

It works fine until I get a few tables in and then I get an error:

```
ERROR DiskBlockObjectWriter:...
java.io.FileNotFoundException ... (Too many open files)
```

This is because of all the intermediate files spark creates before shuffle.

I thought I could avoid this by unpersisting the data frame (`df.unpersist()`) immediately after using it and going into the next loop, but that doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way I can close all open files after use and before the next loop? Once I finish each loop, I have no more use for that df. I am certain there is no issue with the specific table that it fails on because I can read that specific table into a DF just fine as long as I haven't opened too many other ones previously.

Comment: Spark is lazy, so it's important that the `do_something()` command actually executes something. Assuming that it does, have  you tried `del(df)`?

Comment: If nothing were being executed, spark would not have opened any files in the first place. Also, no, deleting a variable won't close intermediate files.

Comment: Yea using `del` was a shot in the dark. Another idea could be to stop/re-initialize your spark context after ever `N` tables or so. Not a very elegant solution, but it *could* work.